# How to select 1st occurrence of an inner class on a page for css?

Tags: html, css

I need to select the 1st occurrence of the 'inner' class and apply css on it.
I tried :first-child and :first-of-type but something is not correct.
Please help.
what I am looking is something like

```
.inner:first-occurrence
```

I tried the following, and other similar combinations -

```
.outer:nth-child(1) .inner:nth-child(1){}
.outer:nth-child(1) .inner:first-child{}
.outer:nth-of-type(1) .inner{}
.outer:nth-child(1) .inner:nth-of-type(1){}
.inner:first-of-type(){}
.row .inner:firs-of-type{}
.row .inner:first-child{}
```

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="outer col-xs-9">
    <div>some text 1</div>
    <div class="inner">
      ... --select this-- 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer col-xs-3">
    <div>some text 2</div>
    <div class="inner">
      ...
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: .outer.col-xs-9 .inner otherwise it is not possible with CSS selectors

Comment: cant you give it an id ? your divs are created dynamically ?

Comment: @Badiparmagi yes divs get created dynamically so can't specify id, also width class, .col-xs-9, is dynamic.

Comment: @Neelotpal hmm, can you use jquery? you can get first element of `inner` class and apply css on it.

Comment: yes jquery is an option but can it not be done through css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gerard commented, you can use

```
.outer.col-xs-9 .inner { }
```

This works because the first `.outer` element also has the `.col-xs-9` class. If you want to select the `.inner` element of the first `.outer` element without regard to other classes, you can use

```
.row .outer:first-child .inner { }
```

The [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo-class represents the first element within a group of *sibling* elements. The `.inner` elements you have are not sibling elements, but their parents are siblings.

```css
.inner {
  color: blue;
}

.row .outer:first-child .inner {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="outer col-xs-9">
    <div>some text 1</div>
    <div class="inner">
      I should be red
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer col-xs-3">
    <div>some text 2</div>
    <div class="inner">
      I should be blue
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `.row .outer:first-child .inner { }`  is what I wanted, thanks @chazsolo